# Confirmation on cancel button

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, javascript

I have a custom SharePoint designer new form where on cancel button (on ribbon), I want to give a confirmation box.

On clicking **Yes**, it should redirect to `allitems.aspx` and on clicking **No** it should remain on the form and do nothing.

I have implemented the following code.

```
$("#Ribbon\\.ListForm\\.Edit\\.Commit\\.Cancel-Large").removeAttr("onclick");
$("#Ribbon\\.ListForm\\.Edit\\.Commit\\.Cancel-Large").click(function(e){
    if (confirm('The data on this form might have changed. Are you sure you want to close this form?'))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        // Do nothing!
    }
});`
```

I get the confirmation box but whether clicking on **Yes** or **No**, it anyway redirects me to `allitems.aspx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have hidden the original button through css and created exactly the same custom button via javascript and jquery.
It works great.

Here is the code.

```
function overrideCancel() {
    var input = document.createElement('a');
    input.title = "Cancel";
    input.role = "button";
    input.id = "custominput";
    $('.ms-cui-group:first').find('.ms-cui-row-onerow:first').append(input)
    $("#custominput").addClass("ms-cui-ctl-large");

    var firstSpan = document.createElement('span');
    firstSpan.id = "fSpan";
    $("#custominput").append(firstSpan);
    $("#fSpan").addClass("ms-cui-ctl-largeIconContainer");

    var innserSpan = document.createElement('span');
    innserSpan.id = "iSpan";
    $("#fSpan").append(innserSpan);
    $("#iSpan").addClass("ms-cui-img-32by32");
    $("#iSpan").addClass("ms-cui-img-cont-float");
    $("#iSpan").addClass("ms-cui-imageDisabled");

    var cancelImg = document.createElement('img');
    cancelImg.style = "top: -511px;left: -273px";
    cancelImg.src = "/_layouts/15/1033/images/formatmap32x32.png?rev=23";
    $("#iSpan").append(cancelImg);

    var lbl = document.createElement('span');
    lbl.id = "lblSpan";
    $("#custominput").append(lbl);
    $("#lblSpan").addClass("ms-cui-ctl-largelabel");
    $("#lblSpan").text("Cancel");
    $("#custominput").click(function () { Cancel() });
}

function Cancel() {
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/Lists/(ListName)/AllItems.aspx";
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to close this form?")) {
        window.location = url;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please return false in case of else condition.

```
function Confirm()
{
  var x = confirm("Are you sure ?");
  if (x)
      return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I've tried that, still on clicking no it redirects

Comment: How you have written redirect code, Could you please share here?

Comment: I haven't written any redirection code, by default Sharepoint cancel button redirects to allitems.aspx.

Comment: As you can see in the first loc, I've even tried to override that by removing onclick attribute, but I guess it doesn't work

Comment: Have you checked in which condition it's going to If Block and when in else block. You can debug in different way- If {Redirect to page A} else {redirect to page B}, see how your code react in this case..

Comment: I tried. It is neither redirecting to page A or page B, it redirects to allitems.aspx

Comment: ??? in my Browser ``confirm( )`` returns a true/false value. What is the point of wrapping it in an extra function *and* return the same value as confirm already returns ??

Answer (score 0):

You are removing the default 'onclick' of the Cancel button so its click can't redirect you to "AllItems.aspx" page unless and until you redirect your page. Refer below code:

```
$("#Ribbon\\.ListForm\\.Edit\\.Commit\\.Cancel-Large").removeAttr("onclick");
$("#Ribbon\\.ListForm\\.Edit\\.Commit\\.Cancel-Large").click(function(e){
    if (confirm('The data on this form might have changed. Are you sure you want to close this form?'))
    {
        window.location = url;  //the url variable contains page location of "AllItems.aspx"
    }
});`
```

@Mayank, please try below code might it works.

```
<script>

function overrideCancel()
{
    //Custom input button
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = "button";
    input.name = "Cancel";
    input.value = "Cancel";
    input.id = "custominput";
    document.querySelectorAll('.ms-toolbar input[value=Cancel]')[1].parentNode.appendChild(input);
    document.getElementById("custominput").setAttribute("class", "ms-ButtonHeightWidth");

    //Hiding already implemented cancel buttons
    document.querySelectorAll('.ms-toolbar input[value=Cancel]')[0].style.display = "none";
    document.querySelectorAll('.ms-toolbar input[value=Cancel]')[1].style.display = "none";

    //this is main logic to move history back
    document.getElementById("custominput").setAttribute("onclick", "Cancel()");
}

function Cancel()
{
    if(confirm("Are you sure to leave the page?"))
    {
        window.location = url;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('overrideCancel');
</script>

<style>
#Ribbon\.ListForm\.Edit\.Commit\.Cancel-Large
{
    display:none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: The click is redirecting me to allitems.aspx

Comment: The click which you set after removing default click is redirecting you to Allitems.aspx page, isn't it?

Comment: When I click cancel, a confirmation box appears. Then whether I click Yes or No, it redirects me to AllItems.aspx. I want this happening only on clicking Yes

Comment: Please add "return false;" in the else part of if condition.

Comment: I've tried that, it's the above answer

Comment: Have you tried to hide the default cancel button and place your custom cancel button?

Comment: I tried making a custom button using Custom Actions on SPD, but its behaviour was the same

Comment: I have edited my answer please refer that.

Comment: Hi, I have written this on my page load. It's not working. Where do I have to call the function?

Comment: Place the code in js file and register your js file in the page. No need to call the function 'overrideCancel' as it is managed by _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.

Comment: Ok, I did it, the cancel button got hidden, but there is no cancel button or custom button visible

Comment: It is visible when I inspect it on elements, but not on ribbon or anywhere else. It's style property is also not hidden

Comment: Ohh I found it, but this is not what the user wants, it should be on the ribbon :/

Comment: Get the id of the element in ribbon under which you need to bind the custom button. And then bind that custom button over there.